# django: related field has invalid lookup

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models

```
class SchoolClass(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    class_name = models.TextField()
    level = models.IntegerField()
    taught_by = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name="teacher_teaching",through='TeachSubject')
    attended_by = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='student_attending',through='StudentClassHistory')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.class_name
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'classes'

class StudentClassHistory(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=datetime.date.today().year)
    semester = models.IntegerField()
    attended_class  = models.ForeignKey(SchoolClass) 

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'student_class_history'
```

When i try to run the following query

```
User.objects.filter(student_attending__studentclasshistory__year=2011)
```

i got the error `Related Field has invalid lookup: year`. That's strange, because i omitted year and the available fields are  `Cannot resolve keyword '' into field. Choices are: attended_class, id, semester, student, year`

How is this so?

Also, with `through` in my model attribute, can I just remove `related_name`?

Answer (score 24):

The problem is that [`year` is a field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#year), so Django thinks you're trying to extract the year from something which isn't a date. You should write:

```
User.objects.filter(student_attending__studentclasshistory__year__exact=2011)
```

(Also, you ought to make the `default` for `year` a callable, i.e.:

```
year = models.IntegerField(default=lambda: datetime.date.today().year)
```

)

Comment: bahh, that explains it. thanks. another qns: if i type filter(student_attending__schoolclasshistory=...) i get a repeated terms in my query i.e proportional to the number of entries in schoolclasshistory. however filter(schoolclasshistory=..) is good. why is this so?